# connecting to a large Oracle database in C#

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I'm new to Oracle in general (moving from SQL Server, not by choice), so apologies if this is a stupid question.

I've added the `System.Data.OracleClient` reference to my C# Windows Forms project in VS2012 , and I'm able to connect successfully to a remote Oracle database in the Data Source Configuration Wizard by selecting Dataset > Database (though not in Entity Data Model, but that's not the issue). However, when I get to "Choose Your Database Objects", I'm trying to select a significant number of them, and the application freezes when I click Finish.

The database is somewhat complex, and I will likely need most (if not all) of the tables in the coming week or so. Is there a better way to connect to the database directly, instead of going through the DSCW?

Comment: You should use the oracle client which is maintained by [oracle itself](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Data.OracleClient has been depricated for a while, last used with 2.0 I think.  Oracle's ODP.net is the recommended client.  It leverages OCI and can access a lot of Oracle-specific features such as bulk inserts and updates.  System.Data.OracleClient was also really bad at parameters -- it had a significant performance drag if you tried to use bind variables.

If you want to use Entity, you should consider DevArt's dotConnect.  The free version doesn't support Entity, but the paid one does.  The paid version also does not require an Oracle client on the host machine, which last time I checked, ODP.net still does.  If your employer is paying, it might be worth the upgrade to be able to use Entity.

Other than the fact that System.Data.OracleClient was not great, I can't imagine why adding a lot of DB objects would cause the freeze.  Give ODP.net and/or DevArt a try.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add all the tables at once. Add the tables you want to use. Plus, you can use [code first approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx). (If you prefer database first still it is OK.)

Other option is that if you are using Entity Framework >= 5.0, then you can also use [multiple diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj519700.aspx) to avoid rendering and slowness problems.

Comment: Honestly, for me, the Database First approach is better if this is enterprise. If you have dedicated DBA's and are creating 3 tier systems, model first is the way to go. I have never personally used Code First, although I don't really work without a DBA. If he is doing Database first, it won't hurt to add all the tables if he wanted to. If you don't use them you don't use them.

Comment: @Failsafe I wasn't sure if he has DBAs and in both cases they have different advantages. For example in big companies you might have to go through a huge waiting list to add one column into your database. Other problem with adding all the tables is that if you have more than 200 tables then you will have to wait forever to add those tables. So multiple diagrams is a good approach.

Comment: @Tough_Coder Yea that makes sense, especially the last part. I forgot some companies have like 200 kajibillion tables :).

Answer (score 0):

click on this link and follow the instruction. let me know if you see any success

[oracle guideline: Using Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/building_odt.htm#CIHJAHIG)